# Call a method without arguments in Java

Tags: java, methods

I have a code like this:

```
import com.eteks.sweethome3d.SweetHome3D;
import com.eteks.sweethome3d.model.Home;

public class Test extends SweetHome3D {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    new Test().init(args);
  }

  @Override
  public Home createHome() {
    Home home = super.createHome();
    // Modify home as you wish here
    return home;
  }
}
```

and I want to run my method through main.
Do you know how I can do that? I have tried many ways like:

```
createHome();

super.createHome();
```

But it doesn't recognize this type.
I also tried

```
Test test = new Test();
  test.init(args);
  test.createHome();
```

which doesn't create any error, but still, what I want is not done.
And they advised me "You shouldn't call test.createHome(); directly"

Thanks in advance:)

---

The thing is that now it runs my application but when I put this

```
System.out.println("method called");
```

into my method, it is displayed twice...??? Why?

Comment: Who is "they"?  Why are they advising you to not call createHome() directly?  I bet that's why it's not working.  If "they" are correct.

Comment: I use an open source application (Sweethome3d) and I am trying to modify "their" code. And "they" tell me to I shouldn't wall it directly. I also tried  new Test().init(args);, it calls the method twice.

Comment: Ok then you don't need to call that method then if init() is already calling it.  So what you should do is simply override it, implement your logic in createHome() (make sure to call super), and just do new Test().init(args) in main.  And it will work.  Now why it works you'll need to study up Java more to understand how method overriding works.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in invoking `test.createHome()`, and it is the way it should work.

In order to check whether the method is called you can put `System.out.println("method called)` in the `createHome()` method.

Your problem probably lies somewhere else, perhaps in the superclass.

Comment: Actually, it is called 3 times, as it appears in console, but not the expected results...How can I run it indirectly?

Comment: there's no such thing as 'indirect invocation'. If your superclass has some method that both initializes and returns you a Home, then that might be it, but otherwise, you are doing it the right way. If it is called 3 times it means you are calling it three times.

Comment: As for the superclass, there is no problem because I use an open source program in order to create my application:(

Comment: if the code you show is all of your code, and it is certain the the superclass works, then the problem is in your understanding of how the superclass works.

Comment: I guess so...Well, I have to look it with fresh eye tomorrow:) Thanks

Comment: The thing is that now it runs my application but when I put this

System.out.println("method called");
into my method, it is displayed twice...??? Why?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the difference between static methods and instance methods.  createHome is an instance method which means you have to have an instance of that class to call that method.  That's why you can call createHome() from your test variable because test is an instance of Test.  The main method is a static method, and it's associated with Class Test and it doesn't have an instance of Test to invoke that method on.  A Class is a different piece of memory from the instances created from that Class.  However, a Class can have methods and variables associated with it through the use of the static keyword.

Now why it's not working has probably more to do with your code and the assumptions it makes about when that method can be called.  I suppose the init() method is doing some rather large and it's not ready to handle invocations to createHome() because the system hasn't fully started.  Looks like a UI program so there might be some issues with timing and processing events.

It's hard to know why it's not working for you without specific errors.

Comment: For example: (Test.createHome())Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method createHome() from the type Test

 at com.eteks.sweethome3d.Test.main(Blender.java:93)

Comment: As stated in my answer there is no method Test.createHome() because that would be a static method.  And clearly from your code and error, there is no static method createHome().  That's what that error is telling you.  That is NOT the compiled output the last section of code you showed.  You probably have old compiled code in there somehow.  I'd suggest rebuilding your project with the code that is correct, and redeploy.